# Trying to refund user from facebook api explorer get "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to refund user manually from Facebook API explorer and get

> {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", 
>       "type": "OAuthException", 
>       "code": 15
>     }
>   }

I read the facebook documents from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/disputes/ and they explain that i need to post https://graph.facebook.com/ORDER_ID?access_token=TOKEN&status=refunded&message=refunding%20order&method=post this so i replaced the order_id_and click on the my application get the access token replaced this parameter as well, but i still can't get it work, also i've changed the method to post.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the access token you're using an app access token or a user access token? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

The app token shouldn't be the one they give you on Facebook API Explorer, but it should be
Application ID | App Secret in the following form: appId|appSecret